# How can I add to the solr score of each document a value from an external file field?

Tags: solr

I am using solr 4.5 and I have an external file with values for some of the documents of my index.

The question is what is the query syntax in order to **add** to the score calculated for each document a value from an external file field?

Alternatively, could we sort on the score+value from external file filed of each document?

Thank you,

**Solved** by including bf=sum("external field") on the edismax

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field similar to **score** for each document. That value can be calculated from external file field for each document and store to Solr. Also, you can sort your result on that field.

[Solr scoring](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/scoring.html) is it's internal mechanism for each Solr document to give some rank.